# IPC Discord javascript, communicate with client of users who autorize to an application

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, discord.js, ipc, rpc

I'm here because I want to propose an application that automates tasks. I'm working on discord.js, and I want to send specific messages on channels (users can choose, but that I know how to do), I already made a system to get an access token after oauth2 authentication, but now I don't know how to send a message thanks to the 'rpc' allowed in the oath2 link. I'm not good at explanations, so let me know if you want me to explain in more detail.

I look the docs but I don't understand how do it, so i'm stuck...